# NSInvalidArgumentException - Unrecognised Selector Sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar, uigesturerecognizer

I know this is going to be something really stupid, but I've been trying to figure it out for 2 days now, so am conceding defeat.

I am trying to implement a Double Tap Gesture recogniser on a NavBar. However when double tapping it I get the following crash....

```
2014-10-11 13:05:01.317 Gesture[4811:152609] -[UINavigationBar navigationBarDoubleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78818150
2014-10-11 13:05:01.321 Gesture[4811:152609] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationBar navigationBarDoubleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78818150'
```

Its a plain View Controller, with a Navigation Bar added to the view. I instantiate the gesture recogniser with this in ViewDidLoad ...

```
.h
IBOutlet UINavigationBar    *navBar;
UITapGestureRecognizer      *tapRecon;

.m (viewDidLoad)
//Add double tap gesture to Navbar For Auto Refresh
tapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
            initWithTarget:navBar action:@selector(navigationBarDoubleTap:)];
tapRecon.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[navBar addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
```

The DoubleTap Method is

```
(void)navigationBarDoubleTap :(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"Sender: %@", sender);
}
```

I've wired the navBar to my UINavigationBar, and set its delegate to the View. I've also tried the method with and without the (id)sender.

Many Thanks

Plasma

Comment: The problem here is that you are setting the target to the navigation bar itself. Set the target to your view controller and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
tapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navigationBarDoubleTap:)];
tapRecon.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[navBar addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
```

Comment: Now I feel really stupid!!! Thank you so much, I knew it was going to be something simple that I had messed up. Had it working in another project but that used Nav Controller as well. :)